# Mysqli Multi Query

Tags: php, mysqli, php-5.5

So besides the DB connector that I haven't included what could cause me to get this error?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE EventData SET deviceID =   "631403956MB21" WHERE deviceID = "4631403956MB' at line 1"

This is my php mysqli multi query.

```
  $sql =  "UPDATE Device      SET deviceID = \"631403956MB21\" WHERE
  deviceID = \"4631403956MB2\"   ";

  $sql .= "UPDATE EventData   SET deviceID = \"631403956MB21\" WHERE
  deviceID = \"4631403956MB2\"   ";

  $sql .= "UPDATE NotifyQueue SET deviceID = \"631403956MB21\" WHERE
  deviceID = \"4631403956MB2\"   ";

  $sql .= "UPDATE RuleTrigger SET deviceID = \"631403956MB21\" WHERE
  deviceID = \"4631403956MB2\"   ";

  $sql .= "UPDATE RuleList    SET deviceID = \"631403956MB21\" WHERE
  deviceID = \"4631403956MB2\"   ";

  $result = mysqli_multi_query($db, $sql);

  if ($result)  {
      echo 'true';   
  } else {
      echo 'false';         
      echo mysqli_error($db);   
  }

  mysqli_close($db);
```

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: To make your code more easily readable use single quotes in a double quoted string like `$sql =  "UPDATE Device SET deviceID = '631403956MB21' WHERE
 deviceID = '4631403956MB2'";`

Comment: Are you trying to change a primary key in that statement?

Comment: you are running mysqli_multi_query wrong way. better run separate queries in a loop usual way - it will make less problems for you.

Comment: This exact situation is the reason `multi_query` exists.  It's a lot faster than executing single queries in a loop, so I would advise the OP to just learn how to use it properly. The only problem with the code posted is that the queries are not separated by `;`.

Answer (score 1):

Disable auto commit when inserting/updating multiple queries and use a loop:

```
$mysqli = dbConnect(); // Connect with database
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); // Set autocommit off

// You can prepare and bind outside the foreach loop, so you don't 
// have to write and bind each query individually.

$sql = "UPDATE RuleList SET deviceID = ? WHERE deviceID = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $deviceID1, $deviceID2);

foreach($ids as $id):
    $deviceId1 = $id;
    $stmt->execute();
endforeach;

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->commit(); // Commit all queries
$mysqli->close();
```

The above is an example

Comment: Thank you for your recent contributions. It seems you know what are you talking about - a rare thing here. Please visit more.

Comment: @YourCommonSense it's really not nice to put down people who spend time trying to help you.  @rhazen your solution is interesting thanks for sharing. I ran some timing tests updating 3,000 rows using both your method and mine and the results are very different. By creating one prepared statement and calling `execute` in a loop as you do, the process lasts about 550 milliseconds on my setup. By escaping the variables, building a queries array and using a single `multi_query` call as I do in my solution, the same DB updates take only about 7 milliseconds. Almost 100x faster.

Comment: @BeetleJuice are you sure you used all this code including a transaction?

Comment: @BeetleJuice haven't tested any speeds, but I was under the impression that auto commit with prepared statements was faster, again, didn't test It, it is saver though, without bind params your open to SQL-injection.

Comment: Thank you for this. I appreciate all the help and suggestions.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes all in one transaction. @rhazen You're right about that, prepared statements are definitely safer. Using `multi_query` is much faster but it puts the burden on the developer to really think about whether the values are escaped or (if they're numerical) to cast them to numbers before including them in the query

Comment: @Beet it cannot be "much" faster. There is just no ground for that. There is some measurement error on your part

Comment: Maybe you're right but I ran my tests several times because I was also surprised by the outcome and got consistent results, so unless you generate data to the contrary, I can't just take your word for it.

Answer (score 1):

Correct query:

```
UPDATE Device      SET deviceID = '631403956MB21' WHERE deviceID = '4631403956MB2';
UPDATE EventData   SET deviceID = '631403956MB21' WHERE deviceID = '4631403956MB2';
...
```

So, finally, you did not assign ";" at the end of each query. You assign only one ";" at the end of php code.

```
$sql =  "UPDATE Device      SET deviceID = \"631403956MB21\" WHERE
deviceID = \"4631403956MB2\"   ";
$sql .= "UPDATE EventData   SET deviceID = \"631403956MB21\" WHERE
deviceID = \"4631403956MB2\"   ";
...
```

↓↓↓

```
$sql =  "UPDATE Device      SET deviceID = '631403956MB21' WHERE
deviceID = '4631403956MB2';   ";
$sql .= "UPDATE EventData   SET deviceID = '631403956MB21' WHERE
deviceID = '4631403956MB2';   ";
...
```

Please try and hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

you should not have multiple `UPDATE` clauses in the same query. You're attempting to use `mysqli_multi_query` but you need to separate your queries with a semi-colon:

First create an array:

```
$queries = [
    "UPDATE Device...",
    "UPDATE EventData...",
    "UPDATE NotifyQueue...",
];
```

From there you have two options. First is to loop through and execute the queries one at a time

```
foreach($queries as $sql):
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    ...
endforeach;
```

This isn't a great idea though because it requires many trips to the DB. The better option is what you're actually trying to do: execute a multi-query statement

```
$multi_query = implode('; ',$queries);
mysqli_multi_query($db, $multi_query);
...
```

**Important Note**

`multi_query` does not use prepared statements, so if you're not careful, you will be vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks. With this approach, be sure to escape your strings and to cast all numerical values as numbers (eg: `$var = (int)$var`) before you include them in the queries.

By the way, I notice that you're making the same change in `deviceID` on multiple tables. This may be a sign that your architecture is poorly designed.  If you have InnoDB tables, you can use primary and foreign keys to indicate that `deviceID` in the `EventData`, `NotifyQueue`... tables is a foreign key linked to the primary key in the `Device` table.  Then if you set changes to cascade on update, all you would need to do is change the ID in the `Device` table and the DB will take care of changing it everywhere else. Here is a [quick intro to the concept](https://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/).

Comment: This is hardly an answer. Use comments when you want to comment

Comment: Thanks; you caught me in the midst of rewriting. If the revised answer satisfies you, please remove the downvote.